# Exclude uuid from url in big-query query using regular expression

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I have a table with url of the form:

```
/api/v2/order/3882-f4e2-0023-fe56
```

I want to group the urls excluding the uuid for the order. I have tried with the following function:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... 
GROUP BY REGEXP_EXTRACT(url , '(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+(?:(\\/(([a-fA-F0-9]{4}(-)*)){4}))')
```

But I get the following error:

> Error: Exactly one capturing group must be specified

I have tried the regular expression in this online test site and it matches the desired url: https://regexr.com/40tjs

Comment: Try `(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/[a-fA-F0-9]{4}(?:-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}){3})`. The current error is related to the fact you have too many (more than 1) capturing parentheses, you should only have one pair of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to minimally adjust your original expression (for BigQuery Standard SQL)

REGEXP_EXTRACT(url , r'((?:/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+)(?:/(?:(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-)*){4})')

gives below for `'/api/v2/order/3882-f4e2-0023-fe56'`

```
    /api/v2/order
```

Comment: I'm still trying to understand why so many nested non-capturing groups (?:) are needed for matching the order uuid, and why one is needed for matching the base url ('/api/v2/order')

Comment: as I mentioned  - I just modified your regexp - by marking those groups as a not-capturing groups by adding `?:` and leaving only one capturing group - so it works! :o) consider voting up the answer if it helped you